# SELECT DISTINCT and ORDER BY

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-order-by, distinct

If I place DISTINCT keyword i get an error other wise it is working fine.

**ERROR: Msg 145, Level 15, State 1, Procedure SP_Products_GetList, Line 15
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Products_GetList]    

@CatID int,
@CatName int,
@IsNew bit,
@InActive bit,
@SortBy varchar(50),
@SortType varchar(50)

AS    

SELECT DISTINCT Products.ProductID, ProductName, MAX(Price) Price, PriceID, [Description], Size, IsNew, InActive FROM (SELECT * FROM Products WHERE (@InActive is null or @InActive = InActive  ) AND ( @IsNew is null or @IsNew = IsNew )) Products
    INNER JOIN  ProductCategory
        on Products.ProductID = ProductCategory.ProductID 
    INNER JOIN  (
                    SELECT * FROM Categories 
                        WHERE 
                            ( @CatID is null or @CatID = CatID ) and
                            ( @CatName is null or @CatName = CatName )
                ) Categories 
        on ProductCategory.CatID = Categories.CatID 
    INNER JOIN ( 
                    SELECT Prices.ProductID, Prices.Price, Prices.PriceID, Prices.SizeID  FROM Prices 
                        INNER JOIN (
                            SELECT ProductID, max(Price) Price from Prices WHERE PriceID IN 
                                    ( SELECT MAX(PriceID) FROM Prices 
                                    GROUP BY ProductID , SizeID)
                            GROUP BY ProductID )  Prices_
                        ON Prices.ProductID = Prices_.ProductID AND Prices.Price = Prices_.Price                     
                ) as Prices 
        on Prices.ProductID = Products.ProductID 
        inner join  Sizes 
        on Sizes.SizeID = Prices.SizeID 
GROUP BY ProductName, CatName, Products.ProductID, Price, PriceID, [Description] ,Size, IsNew,InActive 
ORDER BY 
CASE @SortType 
    WHEN 'desc' THEN  
    CASE @SortBy         
        WHEN 'ProductName' THEN ProductName        
        END  
    END 
    DESC, 
CASE @SortType 
    WHEN 'desc' THEN  
    CASE @SortBy         
        WHEN 'ProductID' THEN Products.ProductID
        WHEN 'Price' THEN Price          
        END  
    END 
    DESC,     
CASE @SortType 
    WHEN 'asc' THEN  
    CASE @SortBy         
        WHEN 'ProductName' THEN ProductName        
        END  
    END 
    ASC, 
CASE @SortType 
    WHEN 'asc' THEN  
    CASE @SortBy         
        WHEN 'ProductID' THEN Products.ProductID
        WHEN 'Price' THEN Price          
        END  
    END 
    ASC
```

Comment: Who wants to find the needle?

Comment: Just a Hint: try to avoid using SELECT * for performance reasons...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What happens if you do...

```
SELECT ProductID, ProductName...
FROM (
       SELECT DISTINCT Products.ProductID, ProductName...
) AS OrderProduct
ORDER BY [your order code...]
```

Answer (score 3):

So, a couple things here.  I'm not saying I'm absolutely sure these are right but a few things to consider.

1. This message usually appears when you don't supply your order by column in the select distinct list.  The only issue I could see here is that since [Price] is the alias of Max(Price) it is possibly confused?  Try specifying Max(Price) in the dynamic order by clauses you are building at the bottom.
2. I noticed that your dynamic order by could potentially have a couple different types returned.  You typically want to keep these order by clauses working with the same data type.  However, it looks like you separated out the sort types (product id & price which I guess are numeric and productname which I would assume is a varchar).

So, nevermind 2, but give 1 a shot.

Comment: @Nix Thanx dear but I tested both option. It is not resolving issue. but Mr.Yves M. has given solution now

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem when trying to order by a calculation on my table (I was trying to order by the distance of a record based on the latitude and longitude columns).

I would get the error even though I included the latitude and longitude columns in my select.

I found it worked if I included the same calculation in my select:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ProductID, ProductName, ({my calculation}) AS distance
FROM my_table
ORDER BY {my calculation} ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the following syntax

`SELECT DISTINCT (Products.ProductID), ProductName, MAX(Price) Price,`

Previous syntax is giving you error because of you have used column `Products.ProductID` many times in a procedure.

I have faced the same problem lot many times. So, above solutions had worked for me. Please try this with your procedure as i have not proper schema to test it.

Comment: @Nix Thanks for your suggestion but it is not working i tried.

Answer (score 0):

A solution to work around `DISTINCT` would be as follows:

```
SELECT productName, productPrice
FROM Product
GROUP BY productName, productPrice
ORDER BY productName
```